# How to handle multiple games with the same exact name?

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

[Need for Speed: Most Wanted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_for_Speed:_Most_Wanted_%282005_video_game%29) is the 2005 EA Black Box game <s>that's imho the only Need for Speed game worth playing of the titles I've tried so far.</s> Box art straight from Wikipedia:

[image: enter link description here]

[Need for Speed: Most Wanted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_for_Speed:_Most_Wanted_%282012_video_game%29) is the 2012 Criterion Game title that's just about to be released. <s>The Wikipedia article doesn't mention out-of-race cop pursuits so the game's worthless.</s> Still from Wikipedia:

[image: enter link description here]

<s>Personal opinions aside,</s> how do we handle this?

Comment: Note, Prince of persia has a similar problem: [tag:prince-of-persia], [tag:prince-of-persia-08]

Comment: The rating's still pending for the older one, huh?

Comment: Anecdotal and irrelevant, but the first time I saw the commercial for this game I got it confused up with NFS: Hot Pursuit and thought they had inexplicably relaunched the title for the *third* time.

Comment: [tag:burnout-7]

Comment: Just adding another aspect: There are some games out there that have years attached: anno-1404, anno-2070, [earth-2150](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_2150) etc. While it is highly unlikely that they will overlap it is still possible.

Comment: @ayckoster Just wait till they remake a game like FIFA 1995 and imagine the tag :)

Comment: Related: [Are we making new tags for duplicate game names hard(er) to use?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11584/4797)

Answer (score 11):

Inspired by how Wikipedia handled this, I've for now tentatively renamed [nfs-most-wanted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-most-wanted) to [nfs-most-wanted-2005](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-most-wanted-2005), while removing the [need-for-speed-mw](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-mw) synonym by Grace that apparently never got used anyway.

The idea is that questions about the new game would be tagged [nfs-most-wanted-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-most-wanted-2012).

Comment: Is it possible to assume no two games with the same name get released in the same year? Pretty please?

Comment: We can't. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 6):

For games which are released in different years, append the year (if needed, shortened to two digits):

[nfs-most-wanted-2005](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-most-wanted-2005) vs. [nfs-most-wanted-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-most-wanted-2012)

... or ...

[nfs-most-wanted-05](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-most-wanted-05) vs. [nfs-most-wanted-12](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-most-wanted-12)

... or ...

[legend-1984](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-1984) vs. [legend-1989](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-1989) vs. [legend-1991](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-1991) vs. [legend-1992](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-1992) vs. [legend-1994](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-1994) vs. [legend-1998](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-1998) vs. [legend-2009](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legend-2009) <sup>*)</sup>

The first version is preferred if the tag length allows for it to not be so easily confused with serial numbers.

For the very unlikely case of games released in the same year, or where the name or serial number includes a year-like string, append one of the following, in decreasing order of usefulness:

- the publisher or studio (whatever is more well known)
- the platform, if the games are single-platform games for different ones
- the genre
- the country of origin

Example (both released 2009)<sup>**)</sup>

[pinball-magma-mobile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pinball-magma-mobile) vs. [pinball-tiny-diversions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pinball-tiny-diversions)

... or (in case those tags would be too long) since both are single-platform releases ...

[pinball-android](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pinball-android) vs. [pinball-ios](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pinball-ios)

---

<sup>*)</sup> Source: [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/search/index.html?game=legend). If I missed any, correct me please.

<sup>**)</sup> Sources: [Magma Mobile web page](http://www.magmamobile.com/mobile_games.html) ("Magma Mobile launched the first Android Pinball game in October 2009") and [Apple's iTunes store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pinball/id304439923?mt=8) ("Released: Feb 10, 2009").

Comment: I find that putting XXXX instead of XX makes it very clear that it's a year. Putting `legend-11` or something might make me think it's the 11th in the series.

Comment: @corsiKa That's why I suggested to only go for the two-digit year if the four-digit one would exceed the tag length limit.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Martin Sojka in appending the year.

This is exactly what is currently done on our sister site Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange:

- [aladdin-1992](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aladdin-1992) vs [aladdin-2019](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aladdin-2019)
- [batman-1966](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman-1966) vs [batman-1989](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman-1989)
- [the-flash-1990](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-flash-1990) vs [the-flash-2014](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-flash-2014)
- [the-incredible-hulk-1978](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-incredible-hulk-1978) vs [the-incredible-hulk-2008](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-incredible-hulk-2008)
- [teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-1987](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-1987) vs [teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-2003](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-2003)

Answer (score -4):

I suggest creating a tag synonym for the title alone to the latest game's tag, i.e. [nfs-most-wanted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-most-wanted) > [nfs-most-wanted-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-most-wanted-2012). I would assume unaware users will inevitably tag their questions regarding the latest game without the mentioning the year (perhaps unaware of an older game named the same).

Comment: Disagree. It would surpise someone when the tag they used no longer points to the game they play.

Comment: point taken, just my 2 cents. However I think games with the same name aren't that often and usually have a few years in between. So I don't think it will matter to them the tag has been relocated to the newer release