# How do we handle Simcity (1989) and Simcity (2013)?

Tags: discussion, tags

So we've already discussed [how to handle this scenario in the general case](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5473/how-to-handle-multiple-games-with-the-same-exact-name). Now for what concerns this specific situation, what should we do?

- **[simcity-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-classic) vs [simcity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity)**
  It seems that the owners of the game franchise themselves now refer to the original game as [Simcity Classic](http://www.simcity.com/en_US/product/simcity-classic). The original game, after all, is now 23 years old and if we haven't gotten questions about it why would we start *now*?
- **[simcity-1989](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-1989) vs [simcity-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-2013)** and a [simcity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity) synonym pointing to the latter.
  ...or we could have none of their history retconning crap and do things our way, Electronic Arts be damned. Google should be smart enough to use the year in the title to know what we're talking about anyway, right?

Comment: What is wrong with simcity-5? Technically it is the fifth game in the series.

Comment: @user28015 I would assume that simcity-5 Qs would get mistagged simcity in that case.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I suggest [simcity-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-classic) for the 1989 release.  It's been SimCity Classic for a long, long time now, (at least as far as I can remember into internet history...) and I doubt anybody familiar enough with the series to be playing the original is going to read a SimCity 2013 question and get confused.

Since we're likely to get a large number of questions related to the 2013 release, keeping the tag short and unambiguous seems like a smart route.  Whatever the "real" tag for the 2013 release is, [simcity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity) should probably point to it.  [simcity-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-2013) seems fine to me.

Comment: +1 I see no issues with the new one being strictly "simcity", and simcity-classic seems a better choice than simcity-1989

Comment: +1; I also prefer to have simsity-2013 as the official tag and simcity pointing to it.

Comment: Someone should update the description for the #simcity tag. It now is a description for the #simcity-classic tag. And even though there are no questions related to this tag it only seems right to explain better that the tag has been "upgraded"

Answer (score 3):

Is this really a problem?  The original has no questions under any tag.  Hell, a good chunk of our user base wasn't even born when the original came out.  The new version, however, should receive a decent number of questions, probably on the level of Borderlands 2.  It deserves the tag all to its own.

Having said that, we probably should have something in place in the unlikely instance that someone does have a question about the original.  Use the first option as the main tags, and then the tags with years as synonyms.

Comment: It is a problem as in there's been much heated discussion on how to handle the tag.

Comment: Really? Must have missed those chat sessions.

Comment: There WAS a question with the simcity tag; it got changed to simcity-classic, which is what spawned the conversation.

Comment: Then that question must have been deleted, because there's nothing in [tag:simcity-classic], and there wasn't anything this morning when I wrote the answer.

Comment: @MBraedley Yep. It was deleted.

Comment: It was off topic so I figured we might as well start from a clean state