# Rename [simcity] tag to [simcity-5] or [simcity-2013]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

[A few years back](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6818/181240), Arqade decided that [simcity-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-classic) would to refer to Simcity (1989), while [simcity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity) would refer to Sim City (2013).

However, the tag name [simcity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity) doesn't give the impression it would apply to a specific game in the series. I've seen a few posts mistakenly using [simcity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity), rather than using the correct game-specific tag like [simcity-3000](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-3000) or [simcity-buildit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-buildit).

I propose renaming [simcity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity) to either [simcity-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-5) or [simcity-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-2013) to make the distinction more clear.

Comment: If there are questions about the sim city series, we should just have a [simcity-series] tag. Renaming one tag in the series might prevent that one from being misused but I don't think it solves the underlying issue. Also, the accepted answer on that meta seems to indicate that the desired tag was actually [simcity-2013] while [simcity] was a synonym for it.

Comment: @Vemonus whether or not that was the desired result, currently the reverse is true. [simcity-2013] is a synonym for [simcity]

Comment: @Vemonus Also, I don't think we need a tag to refer to SimCity as a franchise. There weren't really any questions I saw that applied to the franchise as a whole

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [simcity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity) tag has been renamed to [simcity-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-2013).

[image: renaming simcity tag]

Ironically, it seems that [simcity-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-2013) was already a synonym for [simcity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity). It's just [never been used before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249979/351462).

[image: old tag synonyms]

Thanks to [badp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/23/badp) for renaming the tag.

Answer (score 10):

The [simcity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity) tag should be a synonym for [simcity-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-2013).  That way, if they come out with a new title that they also want to call SimCity, we could just change the synonym.

[sonic-the-hedgehog-2006](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-the-hedgehog-2006) and [tomb-raider-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tomb-raider-2013) are other examples of games where the tag name differs from the official name.  Not to mention [simcity-classic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-classic), which was named SimCity when it was released.

The reason for this is that if someone enters [simcity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity) and it turns into [simcity-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-2013), then they know that they are doing the wrong thing if they meant [simcity-3000](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-3000) or [simcity-buildit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-buildit).  And the suggestions will show the specific tags rather than the synonym.  So people will have to manually type in the whole word rather than just enough to get the suggestion.

Comment: As the top user of the [simcity] tag, I agree.

Answer (score -4):

I don't think it should be renamed. Not that I wouldn't prefer it that way, but because officially the title is SimCity, and it's even like that in the [Box Art](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCZvZ.jpg).

That comes in contrast with other SimCity games such as [Sim City 2000 (1993)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/pt/thumb/4/45/SimCity_2000_cover.png/250px-SimCity_2000_cover.png), [Sim City 3000 (1999)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a6/SimCity_3000_Coverart.png) or my personal favourite [Sim City 4 (2003)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d2/SimCity_4_cover.jpg). And of course the Original [SimCity Classic (1989)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/7b/SimCity_Classic_cover_art.jpg/250px-SimCity_Classic_cover_art.jpg) whose original name was simply SimCity, but was renamed afterwards.

We should be striving to make tags as clear as possible, and officially *SimCity* refers to *SimCity (2013)*. What we can do is create a [simcity-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simcity-series) ***if*** it's really needed to have an abragent tag.

Overall, I do believe that we should keep the same, because that's what the game is ***officially*** called.

Comment: In that case, we wouldn't have tags like [sonic-the-hedgehog-2006] or [tomb-raider-2013]. If anything, the original sim city would be a better fit for the [simcity] tag

Comment: No because the original simcity game is no longer called simcity, but instead simcity classic. As per your examples, they're not the same. There are two "Sonic the Hedgehog" games (1991 & 2006), and there are three "Tomb Raider" games (1996, 2000 & 2013). But there's only **one** SimCity game, which is the 2013 version, because the 1989 version isn't called *SimCity*, it's called *SimCity* **Classic**

Comment: Maybe somebody "officially" changed Simcity to Simcity Classic, but I'm still confused every single time I see that tag, and have to go through a couple seconds of reminding myself that they released another game with the same name as the one I played years ago.

Comment: @DCShannon I feel the same way, but if it's the way EA presents the game then we should follow it. After all, arbitrarely selecting names would give the precedence that one could just call any game whatever they want.

Comment: @Oak It's far from arbitrary, and we don't use the exact, full, official game name for all kinds of games. There would still be a synonym with the (current) official name. That suggestion of a precedence for calling any game whatever we want doesn't seem like a serious argument.