# Prey-2017 or just Prey?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Our first Prey question has been posted!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/308420/purchasing-and-resetting-neuromods) But is it [Prey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prey_(2017_video_game)) or [Prey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prey_(2006_video_game))?

Based off reading the question, and current events, it's likely [Prey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prey_(2017_video_game)) (the new one).  However, what if someone wants to tag the original Prey which was released in 2006? Granted we currently do not have a tag for the original game, it is still possible someone may post a question about.  Considering the release of the new one, I can see an influx of people playing the original Prey (possibly).

Thoughts?  Should the Prey 2017 tag really be [prey-2017](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prey-2017)? Similiar to [doom](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doom) and [doom-2016](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doom-2016)?

Comment: I think I agree with you, we ought to go with Prey-2017 to follow similar tag structures.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I would agree too, but given the answer below, I actually feel that way is appropriate.

Comment: It's a fair point, I can see it. The original DOOM was a lot more popular than the original Prey.

Comment: Related meta discussions: [“How to handle multiple games with the same exact name?”](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5473/4797) (2012) and [“Are we making new tags for duplicate game names hard(er) to use?”](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11584/4797) (2016).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

May I suggest in this case that we have [prey](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prey) (for the new one) and [prey-2006](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prey-2006) (for the old one)? The old one still doesn't have any questions, so we should reserve the shorter tag for the game that is more popular at the moment.

Comment: Either way works. As long as there is a distinction between the two.  There is a good chance we won't see an original prey question.