# Do we need Resident Evil 2 - Remake tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Just seen this question - [Do zombies always get up eventually?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/345561/144891) . Author asks if we need new tag for remake.

I think situation is similar to Prey - [Prey-2017 or just Prey?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12418/144891) .

Right now there are only 2 questions with this tag - one about old game ported to PS Vita and one about RE2 remake which is just released. I think that new game is pretty solid and we can expect some questions about it.

How about having [resident-evil-2-1998](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2-1998) and [resident-evil-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2) for 2019 remake?

Comment: Related meta discussions: [“How to handle multiple games with the same exact name?”](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5473/4797) (2012) and [“Are we making new tags for duplicate game names hard(er) to use?”](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11584/4797) (2016).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed with your suggestion, and so I've gone ahead and retagged that older question to [resident-evil-2-1998](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resident-evil-2-1998). I highly doubt we're going to suddenly find ourselves overrun with questions for the original, so might as well use the shorter tag for the more recent game.

I've also gone ahead and added a tag excerpt to each game to make it clear which tag applies to which version.

Comment: Great, thank you!