# How should the Link’s Awakening remake be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

The remake of Link’s Awakening for the Switch was officially released on September 20th, 2019. And we already have a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/357982/124566) for this game. However, the question was tagged with the [zelda-links-awakening](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-links-awakening), which was created for the original and DX versions of the game.

I suggest there be a new tag created for this version of the game, but I am not sure which one would be best:

• [zelda-links-awakening-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-links-awakening-hd) - This fits the style of other Zelda games, such as [zelda-twilight-princess-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-twilight-princess-hd) and [zelda-wind-waker-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-wind-waker-hd). But with these remakes, ”HD” is officially apart of the title where as Links Awakening does not have it.

•  [zelda-links-awakening-2019](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-links-awakening-2019) - We have done this with other games, like [Prey vs Prey 2006](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12418/124566), to define a clear distinction between the two

For the future questions that will ask about this game, which new tag
 should be used?

Comment: Could also do -switch possibly, but personally I think 2019 makes sense here

Comment: @Unionhawk -2019 makes most sense to me as well, but wanted to see what the community thought before I started editing question(s)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[zelda-links-awakening-2019](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zelda-links-awakening-2019) makes the most sense to me. HD isn't really accurate, since it's a full blown remake, not just a remaster or textures upgrades. A new tag is definitely needed, since there's some new content (more seashells, the chamber dungeons) and  the "physics" are different enough that some new strategies are present (most notable, you can now aim your shield at an angle, making those flying floor tiles room trivial).

Comment: I concur with adding `-2019` to the new tag. I haven't play it (yet) or read much on it, so I was unaware about the new content and physics. As such, appending `-hd` is not a good fit. `zelda-links-awakening-2019` has been created, and question re-tagged