# Same tag is being used for Star Wars: Battlefront (Pandemic Studios) and Star Wars: Battlefront (EA DICE)

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

We have [star-wars-battlefront](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront) that unfortunately does not distinguish between the 2004 *Star Wars: Battlefront* by Pandemic Studios and the 2015 *Star Wars: Battlefront* by EA DICE. Similarly, [star-wars-battlefront-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront-2) does not distinguish between the 2005 *Star Wars: Battlefront II* by Pandemic Studios and the 2017 *Star Wars: Battlefront II* by EA DICE.

### Some questions about 2004 *Star Wars: Battlefront* by Pandemic Studios

- [Can I get a lightsaber in Battlefront?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/86940/47878)
- [Battlefront: Is there a specific number of units active for each side?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/167545/47878)

### Some questions about 2015 *Star Wars: Battlefront* by EA DICE

- [Can I upgrade my Star Wars: Battlefront edition with Ultimate edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/291794/47878)
- [Is the Cycler Rifle affected by gravity?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/259562/47878)

### Some questions about 2005 *Star Wars: Battlefront II* by Pandemic Studios

- [How do I play multiplayer on Star Wars : Battlefront 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/213989/47878)
- [Buying Star Wars Battlefront II for PC safely](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/292530/47878)

### Some questions about 2017 *Star Wars: Battlefront II* by EA DICE

- [Do review copies of Star Wars Battlefront II receive special crates with better items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/321468/47878)

### So what do we name the new tags?

It seems pretty clear to me that we need a new tag for each game, especially since it's not always easy to distinguish based on the question title or even the content. But what do we name it to? [star-wars-battlefront-2-2017](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront-2-2017) looks a little silly to me. Would [star-wars-battlefront-2-ea](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront-2-ea) be better? Are there other options?

Comment: IIRC, Previous consensus is to add the year of release for the less relevant games, so something like [star-wars-battlefront-2004], [star-wars-battlefront-2-2005] and [star-wars-battlefront], [star-wars-battlefront-2] for the recent titles.

Comment: @Robotnik - Not sure, I raised the issue in the past but seemed to draw criticism for suggesting that legacy tags should be renamed

Comment: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11584/are-we-making-new-tags-for-duplicate-game-names-harder-to-use

Comment: I really see the need to address this now, as I assume in the future we're going to get duplicated names not only with games but also with consoles. I personally think renaming legacy tags is the way to go because for the most part, people don't ask questions about older games, they ask them about newer ones. You don't need to worry about someone looking up star-wars-battlefront-2 and when they really meant star-wars-battlefront-2-2004 because that's going to happen once for every thousand lookups of the new game.

Comment: Related meta discussions: [“How to handle multiple games with the same exact name?”](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5473/4797) (2012) and [“Are we making new tags for duplicate game names hard(er) to use?”](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11584/4797) (2016).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I already touched on this problem before:

[Are we making new tags for duplicate game names hard(er) to use?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11584/are-we-making-new-tags-for-duplicate-game-names-harder-to-use)

It is not my preference, but it would seem that we use the following tags to do things the way we have always done it:

[star-wars-battlefront-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront-2) - original Battlefront 2 questions
[star-wars-battlefront-2-2017](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront-2-2017) - new Battlefront 2 game questions

---

The other option is to revisit the original meta (potentially adding a procedure to reassign legacy game tags once a new game is released with the same name, such as we have seen recently with DOOM, Battlefront and so on).

Part of the original argument for not renaming legacy tags was because it was too much work.  The point made regarding the extra moderation needed to correct tags on the newer questions using the legacy tags didn't seem to have enough weight (but does occur, as I just fixed one of your [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/321468/revisions)).  I fixed a few others too for the [star-wars-battlefront](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront) containing [sw-battlefront-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sw-battlefront-2015) questions, but I suspect a few more also need migrating.