# Rename [sw-battlefront-2015] to [star-wars-battlefront-2015]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-rename-request

If you are asking a question and trying to add a tag for one of the *Star Wars: Battlefront* games and type in `star-wars-battlefront`, you get the following tags:

- [star-wars-battlefront](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront)
- [star-wars-battlefront-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront-2)
- [star-wars-battlefront-2-2017](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront-2-2017)

What you don't get is [sw-battlefront-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sw-battlefront-2015), which I think is why a number of questions for that game were incorrectly tagged with [star-wars-battlefront](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront). Heck, when I wrote the meta question [Same tag is being used for Star Wars: Battlefront (Pandemic Studios) and Star Wars: Battlefront (EA DICE)](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12698/47878), I didn't even know that tag existed!

Could we please rename [sw-battlefront-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sw-battlefront-2015) to [star-wars-battlefront-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront-2015)?

Comment: Initially battlefront 2 2017 didn’t have a tag. When I saw the first question tagged [sw-battlefront-2-2017], I made sure to retag it as [star-wars-battlefront-2-2017] before any other questions came up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now done:

[sw-battlefront-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sw-battlefront-2015) -> [star-wars-battlefront-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-battlefront-2015)