# Rename [nfs] tags to [need-for-speed]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I would like to propose renaming the Need for Speed series tags from [nfs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs) to [need-for-speed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed).

Originally [these tags were abbreviated](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1465/181240) to fit the 25 character limit. Now that we have 35 characters, I don't see any reason not to rename these with their full title.

- [nfs-3-hot-pursuit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-3-hot-pursuit) → [need-for-speed-3-hot-pursuit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-3-hot-pursuit) (28)
- [nfs-hot-pursuit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-hot-pursuit) → [need-for-speed-hot-pursuit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-hot-pursuit) (26)
- [nfs-hot-pursuit-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-hot-pursuit-2) → [need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2) (28)
- [nfs-most-wanted-2005](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-most-wanted-2005) → [need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005) (31)
- [nfs-most-wanted-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-most-wanted-2012) → [need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012) (31)
- [nfs-no-limits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-no-limits) → [need-for-speed-no-limits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-no-limits) (24)
- [nfs-pro-street](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-pro-street) → [need-for-speed-prostreet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-prostreet) (24)
- [nfs-rivals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-rivals) → [need-for-speed-rivals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-rivals) (21)
- [nfs-the-run](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-the-run) → [need-for-speed-the-run](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-the-run) (22)
- [nfs-underground](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-underground) → [need-for-speed-underground](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-underground) (26)
- [nfs-underground-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-underground-2) → [need-for-speed-underground-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-underground-2) (28)

**Side note**: The tag descriptions for [*Need for Speed: Hot Pursuit (2010)*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-3-hot-pursuit) and [*Need for Speed 3: Hot Pursuit (1998)*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-hot-pursuit) may need to be edited to prevent confusion between the games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are done:

- [nfs-3-hot-pursuit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-3-hot-pursuit) → [need-for-speed-3-hot-pursuit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-3-hot-pursuit) (28)
- [nfs-hot-pursuit-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-hot-pursuit-2) → [need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2) (28)
- [nfs-most-wanted-2005](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-most-wanted-2005) → [need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005) (31)
- [nfs-most-wanted-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-most-wanted-2012) → [need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012) (31)
- [nfs-underground](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-underground) → [need-for-speed-underground](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-underground) (26)
- [nfs-underground-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-underground-2) → [need-for-speed-underground-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-underground-2) (28)
- [nfs-no-limits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-no-limits) → [need-for-speed-no-limits](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-no-limits) (24)
- [nfs-pro-street](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-pro-street) → [need-for-speed-prostreet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-prostreet) (24)
- [nfs-rivals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-rivals) → [need-for-speed-rivals](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-rivals) (21)
- [nfs-the-run](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-the-run) → [need-for-speed-the-run](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-the-run) (22)

In regards to the 2010 Hot Pursuit game I've renamed it to this:

- [nfs-hot-pursuit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfs-hot-pursuit) → [need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010) (31)

As per [this meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11597/28182) (and reinforced recently [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12702/28182)), new games with the same name as an old game should have the year of release appended, thus for disambiguation purposes I have added the year to this tag.