# Tag merge & synonym request: use official titles for the Diablo tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request, tag-synonyms

As per community consensus in the meta post [Should we standardize our tag formatting regarding Arabic vs. Roman numerals?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12181/4797), we should use the official spelling of the game title in the tags whenever possible, instead of replacing Roman numerals with Arabic numerals.

In line with the meta post, I request that the following tags be merged and synonymized to their official spelling counterparts:

| Current tag (with Arabic numerals) → | Official game title tag |
| --- | --- |
| [diablo-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-2) | [diablo-ii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-ii) |
| [[diablo-2-*]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdiablo-2-*%5D) (multiple tags) | [diablo-ii-*] |
| [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3) | [diablo-iii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-iii) |
| [[diablo-3-*]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdiablo-3-*%5D) (multiple tags) | [diablo-iii-*] |
| [diablo-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-4) | [diablo-iv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-iv) |

Comment: As an aside - I always thought the [meta-tag:retag-request] tag made more sense for scenarios where a retag needs to occur (i.e. via manual edits) rather than tag rename/merge. For example: the [Star Wars Battlefront](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12698/28182) issue (same tag used for two games, necessitating splitting).

Comment: @Robotnik That makes sense. I'll keep that in mind next time I post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully, I got them all.  Comment if you see one I missed!  These are the new tags, and for the most part, their Arabic versions are now synonyms:

| Former tag (with Arabic numerals) → | New Tag Name(s) |
| --- | --- |
| [diablo-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-2) [diablo-2-resurrected](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-2-resurrected) [diablo-2-plugy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-2-plugy) | [diablo-ii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-ii) [diablo-ii-resurrected](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-ii-resurrected) [diablo-ii-plugy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-ii-plugy) |
| [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3) [diablo-3-wizard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-wizard) [diablo-3-monk](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-monk) [diablo-3-demon-hunter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-demon-hunter) [diablo-3-witch-doctor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-witch-doctor) [diablo-3-barbarian](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-barbarian) [diablo-3-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-console) [diablo-3-crusader](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-crusader) [diablo-3-necromancer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-necromancer) [diablo-3-reaper-of-souls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-reaper-of-souls) [diablo-3-ros](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3-ros) | [diablo-iii](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-iii) [diablo-iii-wizard](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-iii-wizard) [diablo-iii-monk](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-iii-monk) [diablo-iii-demon-hunter](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-iii-demon-hunter) [diablo-iii-witch-doctor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-iii-witch-doctor) [diablo-iii-barbarian](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-iii-barbarian) [diablo-iii-console](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-iii-console) [diablo-iii-crusader](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-iii-crusader) [diablo-iii-necromancer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-iii-necromancer) [diablo-iii-reaper-of-souls](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-iii-reaper-of-souls) [diablo-iii-ros](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-iii-ros) |
| [diablo-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-4) | [diablo-iv](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-iv) |